# Linear Algebra Proofs (Diction Understanding) for high school student

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, symmetric-matrices

I am doing a practice homework set where the question asserts if something is necessarily ________?

Does this imply that it is always true for all cases?

For example
Given that X is a symmetric nxn matrix, and Y is a nxn skew-symmetric matrix, which of the following is NECESSARILY true.

1. XYX is symmetric
2. XYX is skew-symmetric
3. XY^2X is symmetric
4. XY^2X is skew-symmetric.

Going by the definition of necessarily being undeniably true, then I can conclude that 2 and 4 are accurate assumptions. However, are 1 and 4 necessarily skew-symmetric if I can list an example proving their validity?

Comment: necessarily, in the context of proofs usually refers to something that follows from some conditions.  that's what a neccesary condition is.  In the e.g,-- if a person is a boy then the person is a human-- "then the person is a human " is necessarily true.  There is also the case of a sufficiently true.  which means the second half of the conditional implies the first.  In the example I just gave, "then the person is a human" is not sufficiently true.

Comment: @johnfowles Thank you for the comment.

Comment: @niing so would 2,3,4 be true in that this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $(XYX)^T=X^TY^TX^T=-XYX$. So, the statement "$XYX$ is symmetric" is false.
2. By the result above, we conclude that the statement "$XYX$ is skew-symmetric" is true.
3. $(XY^2X)^T=(XYYX)^T=X^TY^TY^TX^T=XYYX=XY^2X$. So, the statement "$XY^2X$ is symmetric" is true.
4. By the result above, we conclude that the statement "$XY^2X$ is skew-symmetric" is false.